# Android Google Play Service LocationRequest when using 3G/Cellular Network only

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, 3g

I am developing an application which requests location changes. I have decided on using Google Play Services rather than LocationManager (it causes some problems on newer android versions which are solved with reboot) 
Now I successfully connect to Google Play Services and onConnect the code below is run:

```
@Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Service connected, start listening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1);
            locationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
            locationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                    mLocationListener);
        }
```

This code runs perfectly when there is wi-fi connection, but it will not receive an update with 3G/Cellular Network. I have used priorities NO_POWER and HIGH_ACCURACY as well but they dont work either. 
I have defined COARSE LOCATION and FINE LOCATION permissions in my manifest file.
Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks